# Call Menu Block on CMS Page from two column layout to one column layout in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, page-layouts

I am trying to modify one column layout on my custom theme by adding menu block from two column (left bar layout) in Magento 1.9. I added a snippet of advancedmenu block from column layout from 2 column layout. But it goes in the bottom. I am expecting an output similar like this. How do I place advancedmenu block properly so that both of them come next to each other? How do I do that?

[image]

**2columns-left.phtml**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_content') ?>
    <section class="main-container col2-left-layout  container-width">
        <div class="main"> 
        <div class="column-left-breadcrumbs">
            <div class="breadcumb-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-main-left">
            <article class="col-main">

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </article>
            <aside class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
```

**1-column2.phtml(i cloned one column layout)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home_content') ?>
    <section class="main-container col1-layout">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="column-left-breadcrumbs"> <div class="breadcumb-main">    
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        </div>
        </div>

            <article class="col-main"> 

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </article>
            <aside class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></aside>

        </div>
    </section>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Currently this is how it look on two column layout, but i want to incorporate within one column layout. Please suggest how to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom class OR add `col2-left-layout` class in `section` tag. See the difference below in your `section` tag:

```
<section class="main-container col2-left-layout  container-width">

<section class="main-container col1-layout">
```

Comment: I am adding the code.   There are some bugs in it. I shall revert back solving some layout issues.

Comment: It was not the exactly the answer I was looking for. But it did give me clue to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Good explanation. +1